# Split Schedule of 192 Games into Weeks of 6 Games, Without Repeating Teams

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have coded up a league schedule so that 12 teams are playing a total of 192 games (4 times each against conference opponents, 2 times each against cross-conference opponents). I have also shuffled those games.

My final step is to divide those 192 games into 16 weeks of 6 games each. But, it's important that each team only appear once in any given week (i.e. - only play one game per week). This is the part I'm stuck on.

My schedule array looks something like this:

```
let schedule = ["a : b", "c : d", "e : f", "g : h", "i : j", "k : l", "m : n", "o : p", "q : r", "s : t", "u : v", "x : y", "a : c", "d : f", "g : i", "l : o"]; // remember, this is actually 192 elements long
```

From this array (just remember it has 192 elements, so it's larger than the above, which is an example to show the data structure) I want to generate `week1`, which is an array containing 6 of the elements from the `schedule` array, like so:

```
let week1 = ["a : b", "c : d", "e : f", "g : h", "i : j", "k : l"];
```

The above is what I want as a result. However, I can't just use `schedule.slice(0, 6)` to get 6 elements, because I can end up with teams playing twice, like so:

```
let week1 = ["a : b", "c : d", "a : e", "f : g", "h : i", "j : k"]; // Notice "a" is playing twice here, which I do not want.
```

So, the question is, how can I take 6 games from my array of 192 games, but ensure that each team only appears once in that array of 6 games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const games = ["a : b", "c : d", "e : f", "g : h", "i : j", "k : l", "m : n", "o : p", "q : r", "s : t", "u : v", "x : y", "a : c", "d : f", "g : i", "l : o"];

const teamsTaken = new Set();
const result = [];

for(const game of games) {
  if(result.length >= 6) break;
  
  const [teamA, teamB] = game.split(" : ");
  if(teamsTaken.has(teamA) || teamsTaken.has(teamB)) continue;
  
  teamsTaken.add(teamA);
  teamsTaken.add(teamB);
  
  result.push(game);
 }
 
 console.log(result);
```

Use a Hashtable to exclude duplicates.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas! And two thoughts, for the sake of clarity, "teams" should probably be named "games". And lastly, I would want to then remove those 6 games from the initial array of games, so that when I run this again, I'm not getting the same game showing up in the next round.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the answer to reflect this.